# Finding a specific position within a TimeSeries Forecast

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series

Say I have a timeseriesforecast on a series of data, result in

$10, 30, 50, 100, 400, 700, \ldots$

I want the programme to output the serial number (position in the forecast-series) of the first element larger than 500.

(in the above case, the answer should be 6)

How can I do it?

Comment: `FirstPosition[yourlist, _?(# > 500 &)]` ?

Comment: Position[myList, _?(# > 500 &)] // Flatten